# How to get current server avaible quota to send emails with PHP

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer

im in a development of an website that needs to send massive emails to their users. I have done the PHP script to send emails using PHPMailer and its ok, but the server has a limit by hour to send emails.

I want to know if there's any way to query the current avaible quota to send emails so i can iterate using a for/while/etc and never get the error of mail not send (and get the error though email too).

In this moment im doing something like this:

```
While(...)
{
    if(cont < 200)
    {
         $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
         try
         {
             // send email to current user using PHP mailer
             // and update database to not send him another email until next month.
         }
         catch(Exception $e)
         {
             echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        // Limit reached, dont send more emails.
        break;
    }
    cont++;
}
```

But if I send emails though another scripts (new users, notifications, etc) my quota avaible will be != from my server limit, so this scripts will always send me the error email. I will like to do something like this:

```
$limit_quota = getQuota();
while(...)
{
    if(cont<limit_quota)
    {
        // send emails.. (same code)
    }
    else
    {
        // Limit reached, dont send more emails.
        break;
    }
    cont++;
}
```

Note: Im using CRON to shedule this php script every month.

Comment: sure you could do this, or just move to a server with no limits, there's reason to handicap your self like this.

Comment: I'd be pretty shocked if you could query the server to get the current quota state. I would handle it by learning the approximate quota per hour, and routing all your email through one script that uses a file or a database to keep track of how many emails it's send in the last hour, and stops when it gets too high. Then you could set your scripts quota a little lower than what you've found the server's quota to be

Comment: @tim Yes, i know the reasons for the limits, but when you have more and more users 200/300 emails per hour doesnt fit the needs.

Comment: @Stevish thats could be a solution, do my own count in database.. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: There's no generic API to query for this. Consult your hosting provider and/or management interface.

Comment: @GersonF, I had a program a while back that needed to send thousands of emails, and this is how I handled it. I think I used a database rather than a file

Comment: I dont think you understood my solution, simple move to server (or just a mail server) without such limits, its so much easier than having to do this.

Comment: @tim Oh, now i understand. Do you know any mail server without such limits? My server is paid and have this restriction, doing that would be easier

Comment: there are millions of web hosts and thousand of mail server providers, you need to do your own research to fin don that meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much to all for the help!